# Why my jquery/angular auto-complete input-box does not allow to select from the drop-down list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-ui

I've created an auto-complete drop-down input-box directive by using angularJs and jQuery. Everything is fine except the drop-down list goes away once I want to select an item. So this way I just can filter through the items without selecting them and I have to type the whole string which in my case happens to be very long.

The following is angularjs/jquery code. It includes two directives: the first gets the data that I have queried from laravel interface and have access to it in html; the second is the actual auto-complete input-box angular/jquery directive. These directives use a service for processing and passing data to each other.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [], function() {});

app.factory('sharedProperties', function() {
    var items;
    var newItems = [];
    return {
        getItems: function() {
            for(i in items){
            newItems.push(items[i].country);
            } 
           return newItems;
        },
        setItems: function(value) {
           items = Value;  
        },
    };
});

app.directive('autoCompleteData', function(sharedProperties) {
            return { restrict: 'E', 
                    link:function(scope, element, attrs){
                        scope.items=JSON.parse(attrs.items);
                        sharedProperties.setItems(scope.items);
                      }
                   };
    });




app.directive('autoComplete', function(sharedProperties) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, attrs, ctrl) {
            $(elem).autocomplete({   
            source: sharedProperties.getItems(),
            minLength: 1,
            delay: 300
            });
       }
    };
});
```

The directive's tags that I use in html are like this:

```
<auto-complete-data items="myJsonData"> </auto-complete-data>
<input type="text" auto-complete/>
```

The html links and scripts:

```
<link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css">
<link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

And here is the css code:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }

  html .ui-autocomplete {
    height: 100px;
  }
```

Any ideas how I can get this code to be a working selectable-dropdown-input like [here](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default)?

I've tried to create a working code in jsfiddle for reference, but for some reason my code did not work there.

Comment: Generally speaking, using Angularjs and jQuery combined like this is frowned upon because it can cause issues. Is there any reason you couldn't use one of the plethora of autocomplete/typeheads already in existence for Angularjs?
ex: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: What is the need of `autoCompleteData` and `sharedProperties` here..? Why can't directly to autocomplete directly access the data it..? it doesn't have an isolated scope or anything

Comment: @T J Thank you for looking through my question. Actually I even tried to  have the second directive without getting data from the other directive. So for that I just added an array to the source part of auto complete. And again the same thing: I did get the data in drop-down but without being able to select from them.

Comment: @cDecker32 Thank you for your suggestion. The bootstrap/angular demos  in the link look great. and I've tried the auto-complete input-box that I found there. But it did not work for me. So I guess I need to spend some hours to make it work. In that case I prefer to have a solution for my half way working code.